# Subtract more than two values using variadic

Tags: php

Hi guys I have the following class (it's a simple calculator). The subtract method accepts many parameter in input.

```
class Calculator {

    public function sum($a, $b)
    {
        return $a + $b; 
    }

    public function divide($a, $b)
    {
        return $a / $b;
    }

    public function subtract(int ...$b)
    {   
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($b) - 1; $i++)
        {
            $oldValue = $b[$i];
            $oldValue -= $b[$i+1];
        }
        return $oldValue;
    }

}

$calc = new Calculator();
var_dump($calc->subtract(13,4,5));
```

How can I subtract more than 2 numbers?? I cannot find the right solution for the right implementation of `public function subtract(int ...$b)`
Someone could help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment you're resetting `$oldValue` each time, when you really need to set it in the beginning and go from there.

```
public function subtract(int ...$b)
{
    $oldValue = null;
    foreach($b as $num) {
        if(is_null($oldValue)) {
            $oldValue = $num;
        } else {
            $oldValue -= $num;
        }
    }
    return $oldValue;
}
```

Comment: Thank @aynber! It works perfectly so I was resetting $oldValue each time so I had to put it out from the cycle.. now I have understood. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

public function subtract(int ...$b)
{
    $num = $b[0]; // $num = 13;
    unset($b[0]); // $b = arrray(4,5)
    foreach ($b as $value) {
        $num -= $value;
    }
    return $num;
}
```

**EDIT**

`unset` will not reset index of the array where array_shift will reset the index of array, as per my previous experiments i am writing codes mostly without if conditions inside for loops whenever possible

`unset` O(1) Time complexity

`array_shift` O(n) Time complexity

BenchMarks

```
$max = 5000;
$times_a = [];
$times_b = [];
for ($i = 1; $i <= $max; $i += 1) {
    $start = microtime(TRUE);
    $array = range(0, 10000);
    array_shift($array);
    $end_time = microtime(TRUE);
    $times_a[] = $end_time - $start;
    //benchmark array lookups
    
    $start = microtime(TRUE);
    $array = range(0, 10000);
    unset($array[0]);
    $end_time = microtime(TRUE);
    $times_b[] = $end_time - $start;
}
$times = 0;
foreach ($times_a as $key => $value) {
    if($value > $times_b[$key]){ 
    //if time of array_shift greater than unset
        $times++;
    }
}
echo $times . '<br>'; //4953
echo count($times_a); //5000
// Unset is More usefull
```

If inside forloop

```
$max = 50000;
$times_a = [];
$times_b = [];
$start_time = microtime(TRUE);
for ($i = 1; $i <= $max; $i += 1) {
    $array = range(0, 10000);
    $oldValue = null;
    foreach($array as $num) {
        if(is_null($oldValue)) {
            $oldValue = $num;
        } else {
            $oldValue -= $num;
        }
    }
    $end_time = microtime(TRUE);
}
$end_time = microtime(TRUE);
echo $end_time - $start_time;
//17.108186006546
```

Unset First variable initially

```
$max = 50000;
$times_a = [];
$times_b = [];
$start_time = microtime(TRUE);
for ($i = 1; $i <= $max; $i += 1) {
    $array = range(0, 10000);
    $num = $array[0];
    unset($array[0]);
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        $num -= $value;
    }
    $end_time = microtime(TRUE);
}
$end_time = microtime(TRUE);

echo $end_time - $start_time;

//14.774175882339
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to shift the first number from the argument list, then subtract the sum of the remaining numbers.

```
public function subtract(int ...$b)
{
    $a = array_shift($b);
    return $a - array_sum($b);
}
```

It could also be simplified by modifying the function signature to accept a beginning number as well as a variable-length list of numbers to subtract from it.

```
public function subtract(int $a, int ...$b)
{
    return $a - array_sum($b);
}
```